# Get first value of selected items from a multiple select in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have this code to get the text of the selected option from a  in JavaScript:

```
form_name.select_name.options[form_name.select_name.selectedIndex].text
```

For example, with

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

When user selects 3, the code would return 3.

My question is, when it's a multiple select such as:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

How to return the text of the first selected item in JavaScript? For example, when 2 and 3 are selected, it would return 2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Easy enough to find out... use a JS debugger to see what's in the select's object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="myForm">
<select name="myOption" multiple>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
</select>
<BR><BR>
<input type=submit value="Print First" onClick="printMe()">

<input type=submit value="Print All" onClick="printAll()">

</body>
<script>
function printMe() {
alert ("Selected option is " + myForm.myOption.value);
}

function printAll() {

var str="",i;

for (i=0;i<myForm.myOption.options.length;i++) {
    if (myForm.myOption.options[i].selected) {
        str = str + i + " ";
    }
}

alert("Options selected are " + str);
}


</script>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you want...

I have also provided print all and print first option...

### Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so with jQuery:

```
$('select option:selected').first().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job, and is easily modified to get all values, or a specific index.

```
var selected = ''; // make this into an array to get all / specific value
var mySelect = form_name.select_name;

while(mySelect.selectedIndex != -1)
{
    if(mySelect.selectedIndex != 0)
    {
        selected = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text; // change this to selected.push(...) for all/specific values
    }
}

if (selected.length)
{
    // at least one thing was selected, have fun
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select id="your-select" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getFirstSelected(yourSelectId)
{
  var yourSelect = document.getElementById(yourSelectId);

  var optionLength = yourSelect.options.length;

  for (i = 0; i < optionLength; i++) {
    var option = yourSelect.options[i];

    if (option.selected) {
      return option.value;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

**Usage**

```
var firstSelectedOption = getFirstSelected("your-select");
```

**Edit**

Just realized that this will give you the first selected value and the function is not needed

```
var firstSelectedOption = document.getElementById("your-select").value;
```